# Spring 4, Hibernate. Как настроить?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Начну с того, что гуглил. Уже больше недели ковыряю.
Суть вопроса: как интегрировать Hibernate в Spring, желательно через пул соединений. По отдельности настроить их могу.

Если имеется каркас настроенного веб приложения Spring/Hibernate/MySql/Maven - буду просто счастлив скачать исходники :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте Spring Data JPA.

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ 
Пример с использованием Spring Boot.

Если вы не используйте Spring Boot. То вам понадобится приблизительно такая конфигурация.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.larditrans.gpstracker.repositories.sql")//Пакет в котором искать репозитории
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.larditrans.gpstracker.model")//Пакет в котором искать @Entity
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    @Bean
    //Настройки вашего datasource, в данном случае используется tomcat jdbc pool
    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
        PoolProperties poolProperties = new PoolProperties();
        poolProperties.setUrl(env.getProperty("sql.url"));//uri базы данных
        poolProperties.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");//класс драйвера
        poolProperties.setJmxEnabled(true);
        poolProperties.setUsername(env.getProperty("sql.user"));
        poolProperties.setPassword(env.getProperty("sql.password"));
        poolProperties.setMaxActive(100);
        poolProperties.setInitialSize(10);
        poolProperties.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
        poolProperties.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        poolProperties.setMinIdle(10);
        poolProperties.setJdbcInterceptors(
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;" +
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
        );
        return new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(poolProperties);
    }
    @Bean//Вендор JPA
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource){
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new     EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        //Деалект БД
        vendorAdapter.determineDatabaseDialectClass(Database.POSTGRESQL)

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.larditrans.gpstracker.model");//Пакет с @Entity
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
   }
    @Bean//Менеджер транзакций
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Таки настроил по примеру с использованием Spring Boot. По началу не совсем очевидные настройки в properties. Пришлось пошерстить ещё и тут - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms . Кому интересно, вот сам файл пропертиз:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/customer
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.max-wait=5000
spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
```